# Python: Class instances are classes

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

### Is it possible to create a class whose instances are classes?

At first it seemed possible, but I wondered if this would actually be possible without any external interference.
Eg:

```
NewClass = ClassClass(someArgs)
instance = NewClass(someOtherArgs)
```

**Is this possible? If so, how would it structurally work? Is this even useful?**

Comment: Aren't you searching for `type`?

Comment: provide example code please

Comment: An instance of a class is an object.

Comment: To what end do you want this? If you had it, how would you use it?

Comment: Every instance of a class is an object.  Are you thinking about inheritance?

Comment: It is possible to make the code you wrote work, but not the way you are thinking of. I guess you mistook concepts with inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the type of `1` you get `type(1) == int`. If you check the type of `int` you get `type(int) == type`.

A class whose instances are classes is called a *metaclass* and in Python you create metaclasses by subclassing `type`.

```
class ClassClass(type):
    pass
```

Technically `collections.namedtuple` is a metaclass, but it's actually [cheating](http://jameso.be/2013/08/06/namedtuple.html).

There's a great [PyCon talk by David Beazly about metaprogramming in Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPiWg5jSoZI). It's long, but very interesting. He starts talking about metaclasses around the 27 minute mark.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for metaclasses:

```
class Foo(type):
    # Foo is a subclass of type and just like instances of type are
    # classes, instances of Foo are classes.
    pass

class Bar(object):
    # The Bar class is an instance of Foo
    __metaclass__ = Foo

# You can also create instances of Foo dynamically.
Bar = Foo("Bar", (object,), {})
```

[More on metaclasses.](http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/)

Answer (score 2):

From the Python help:

```
type(name, bases, dict) -> a new type
```

So lets create a simple class:

```
Dog = type('Dog', (object,), {})
```

And now you can create a dog:

```
fido = Dog()
```

If you literally want a class that creates classes, you can do it, by extending type... Honestly I have no idea what you want it for, but here it is:

```
class ClassMaker(type):
    def __new__(self, name):
        return type(name, (object,), {})

NewClass = ClassMaker('NewClass')
print NewClass
```

Comment: That is how to dynamically create classes, which isn't *necessarily* the same thing.

Comment: Ok you are right, I edited, now that is a class that creates classes, right? :)

Comment: This is a little off, metaclasses need to subclass `type`. Using `__metaclass__` makes a class an instance of the metaclass, not an actual metaclass. Adding `__call__` to a class makes instances of that class `callables` not classes.

Comment: @BiRico Ok I know what you mean, it was for effects sake, I just wanted to have a class whose instances are classes, or at least, seam to be. Indeed, this is not a class whose instances are classes, it is basically a function that creates classes hehe

Comment: @BiRico thats it! a type subclass is, technically, a class that creates classes (actually thats what type is). Anyway this is pointless... Thanks for the ideas haha

Answer (score 0):

In (modern) python, classes are first order objects. This is easy to verify by accessing a class' `__class__` property:

```
class A:
    pass

print(A.__class__)
-> <class 'type'>
```

Note that `type`'s class is also `type`:

```
print(type.__class__)
-> <class 'type'>
```

It is possible to actually derive from `type`:

```
class A:
    def do(self):
       print("DOING")


class mytype(type):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return type.__new__(cls, 'mytype', cls.__bases__, {})

    def __init__(self):
        return type.__init__(self, 'mytype', self.__class__.__bases__, {})

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return A(*args, **kwargs)

aClass = mytype()
-> <class '__main__.mytype'>
aObj = aClass()
print(aObj)
-> <__main__.A object at 0xdeadbeaf>
aObj.do()
-> DOING
```

However, with proper [metaclasses](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Metaclasses) I do not see a good reason jumping through such hoops. Even metaclasses are only needed in special cases. Most often, a factory method that returns a class object is sufficient:

```
def ClassClass():
    return A

aClass = ClassClass()
aObj = aClass()
```

Syntax is the same and if the only operation on the factory is instantiation, there is no difference.